# HttpURLConnection redirects my POST request into a GET

Tags: java, http, playframework, httpurlconnection, playframework-1.x

I'm sending a `HttpURLConnection` with `setInstanceFollowRedirects(true)` and `POST`, get a redirect response that looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2013 20:47:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 302 Found
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://foo.bar/...
```

And the next request that the JVM sends is a `GET` request (to the correct, redirected URL). It also seems to drop one of the HTTP headers I added to the original request.

FYI, I'm not using `HttpURLConnection` directly, but rather through Play Framework's WS wrapper.

My question is - is this a known issue with Java (Sun JVM 1.7.0)? Or could it be a bug in Play Framework?

Comment: I assume it's on purpose, as common browsers will do the same.

Comment: @JulianReschke - I'm implementing an API client, and this completely breaks it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Java. You can change it by setting the system property http.strictPostRedirect=true.

For details, please see this quote from the Java source [HttpURLConnection implementation source](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.html):

```
    /* The HTTP/1.1 spec says that a redirect from a POST 
     * *should not* be immediately turned into a GET, and
     * that some HTTP/1.0 clients incorrectly did this.
     * Correct behavior redirects a POST to another POST.
     * Unfortunately, since most browsers have this incorrect
     * behavior, the web works this way now.  Typical usage
     * seems to be:
     *   POST a login code or passwd to a web page.
     *   after validation, the server redirects to another
     *     (welcome) page
     *   The second request is (erroneously) expected to be GET
     * 
     * We will do the incorrect thing (POST-->GET) by default.
     * We will provide the capability to do the "right" thing
     * (POST-->POST) by a system property, "http.strictPostRedirect=true"
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, assuming you control the server: use status code 307.

Comment: Didn't work for me, it still redirects to a GET request.

Comment: Sounds like a Java bug then.